# Why SWIG C# overloads fail?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, inheritance, swig

So having a [simple code in C++](http://ideone.com/ht4U30). Having a C++ library with:

```
class A{
public:
    virtual void Call();
    virtual void CallCall();
    virtual ~A();
};
```

And a swig file:

```
%{
#include "A.h"
%}

%include "A.h"

%module(directors="1") TestSWIG;

%feature("director") A;
```

After calling SWIG generator, including generated C++ and C# files into related projects and rebuilding all projects.

> swig.exe -c++ -csharp -namespace TestSWIG -outdir ./Sharp/TestSWIG -o  ./TestSWIG.cxx TestSWIG.i

We want a simple C# .Net code to work:

```
using System;
using TestSWIG;

namespace ASharp {
    class Cassa : A{
        public override void Call() {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello from C#");
        }
    }

    class Program {
        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            var c = new Cassa();
            c.CallCall();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Yet we see that C++ implementation is the one that gets called

```
void A::Call() {
    std::cout << "Hello from C++ World!" << std::endl;
}
```

Now the question is: what do I do wrong so that inheritance and virtual functions do not work?

Comment: `A` is not inside any namespace in C++ world

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And the answer was... to look into Swig->Examples!=) The problem was in ordering in a `.i` file.

```
%module(directors="1") TestSWIG; // Module name

// Source code refrence
%{
#include "A.h"
%}

%feature("director") A; // objects to support inheritance
%include "A.h" // main file to parse
```

and it worked as required!=)